# How to implement the button css like Spotify play button in the table row

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi I tried to custom my button like Spotify.

When hover the table row show play button and click the play button change image.

[image]

I consulted from other fiddle and updated. Now I click one element and the other one will hide. However, I don't know how to hide one of them in the beginning.

```css
a {
  display: block;
  font-size: 18px;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  border-radius: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
}
a:hover {
  font-size: 18px;
  border: 2px solid green;
  border-radius: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
a:target {
  display: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  border-radius: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<a id="btn" href="#btn">Play</a>
<a id="btn2" href="#btn2">Pause</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do following way using pure css without scripting.

```css
a {
  display: block;
  font-size: 18px;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  border-radius: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
}
a:hover {
  font-size: 18px;
  border: 2px solid green;
  border-radius: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
a:target {
  display: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  border-radius: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
a:nth-last-child(2){
  display:none;
  }
a:first-child:target + a:nth-last-child(2){
  display:block;
  }
```

```html
<a id="btn" href="#btn">Play</a>
<a id="btn2" href="#btn2">Pause</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use inline style and set css property `display` to `none` :

```
<a id="btn2" href="#btn2" style="display:none;">Pause</a>
```

Or using javascript :

```
document.getElementById('btn2').style.display = 'none';
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use single line to achieve this by Jquery. Change the text when the link is clicked.

```
$('.play').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.toggleClass('active');
    if($this.hasClass('active')){
        $this.text('Pause');         
    } else {
        $this.text('Play');
    }
});
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ezpg4qqn/)**